# Constructing std::chrono::system_clock::time_point from a duration

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a data source that provides time since the start of the day (00:00:00Z). I want to construct a `std::chrono::time_point` based in this input.

For the sake of example, the current time is 2020-02-27T01:05:30.687073184. My source provides me a binary-coded decimal value, to 0.01 seconds. I construct intermeditate values to separate the parsing/mediation from the combination.

```cpp
        using Days = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400>>;

        auto hr10  = std::chrono::duration<unsigned, std::ratio<36000>> ( 0 );
        auto hr1   = std::chrono::duration<unsigned, std::ratio<3600>>  ( 1 );
        auto mn10  = std::chrono::duration<unsigned, std::ratio<600>>   ( 0 );
        auto mn1   = std::chrono::duration<unsigned, std::ratio<60>>    ( 5 );
        auto sc10  = std::chrono::duration<unsigned, std::ratio<10>>    ( 3 );
        auto sc1   = std::chrono::duration<unsigned, std::ratio<1>>     ( 0 );
        auto ms100 = std::chrono::duration<unsigned, std::ratio<1, 10>> ( 6 );
        auto ms10  = std::chrono::duration<unsigned, std::ratio<1, 100>>( 8 );

        auto t = hr10 + hr1 + mn10 + mn1 + sc10 + sc1 + ms100 + ms10;  // 393068
        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto sinceEpoch = now.time_since_epoch();      // 1582765530687073184 ns

        auto today = std::chrono::duration_cast<Days>(sinceEpoch);    // 18319 days
        auto sinceDay = sinceEpoch - today;            // 3930687073184 ns

// There is logic to determine if there is a day roll-over; it is not relevant here
        auto adjust = Days(0);

// Create the time_point
        auto tp = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point();
        std::cout << "\n\tnull:       " << tp.time_since_epoch().count();

        tp += today;
        std::cout << "\n\ttoday:      " << tp.time_since_epoch().count();

        tp += adjust;
        std::cout << "\n\tadjust:     " << tp.time_since_epoch().count();

        tp += t;
        std::cout << "\n\tt:          " << tp.time_since_epoch().count();

        std::cout << "\n\tall-in-one: " << decltype(tp)(today+adjust+t).time_since_epoch().count();
```

This results in the following output:

```
        null:       0
        today:      1582761600000000000
        adjust:     1582761600000000000
        t:          1582765530680000000
        all-in-one: 36577304120000000
```

What I don't understand is why incrementally adding each `duration` to the `time_point` produces the desired effect, but trying to construct the `time_point` from an aggregate duration does not.

Comment: That doesn't compile. Why do you ask?

Comment: er.  `std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::time_point().time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';`  Your incremental path adds in `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point()`, and your aggregate does not.  I don't know enough about the APIs to know if this is the problem or not, I just see it as the only obvious difference, besides the potential for overflow and undefined behavior.

Comment: The aggregate is using the `time_point(duration)` constructor. The type of the duration shouldn't matter; in this case it should be convertable without a `duration_cast`, since `system_clock` has greater resolution than 0.01 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When declaring your own duration types, use 64-bit values**

The problem is overflowing the duration when converting from `Days`. Changing the custom duration types to use a 64-bit integer eliminates the problem:

```cpp
        auto hr10  = std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::ratio<36000>> ( std::get<0>(bcd) );
        auto hr1   = std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::ratio<3600>>  ( std::get<1>(bcd) );
        auto mn10  = std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::ratio<600>>   ( std::get<2>(bcd) );
        auto mn1   = std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::ratio<60>>    ( std::get<3>(bcd) );
        auto sc10  = std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::ratio<10>>    ( std::get<4>(bcd) );
        auto sc1   = std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::ratio<1>>     ( std::get<5>(bcd) );
        auto ms100 = std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::ratio<1, 10>> ( std::get<6>(bcd) );
        auto ms10  = std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::ratio<1, 100>>( std::get<7>(bcd) );
```

Or, if that's undesirable, cast `t` to a larger type before adding in `today`:

```cpp
        auto tp = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point(
                      std::chrono::duration_cast::microseconds(t) + today + adjust
                  );
```

**Remember, the number of nanoseconds since 1970 is a big number**, and will certainly overflow a 32-bit quantity.

Answer (score 1):

You are overflowing the tick counter by adding the `duration` objects directly.

You gave the durations tick counter types of `int` and `unsigned`. The common type of these is `unsigned`. Therefore all the math is done in `unsigned` for `today+adjust+t`.

Assuming 32bit `unsigned`, the typical maximum value is `2^32-1 = 4294967295`. The value you expect to get is `1582761600000000000`, which is clearly larger.

Just use `unsigned long long` (or a sufficiently large fixed-size integer type) as `duration` tick counter type.

The type used for `system_clock::duration` (and thus `system_clock::time_point`) has probably higher rank than `unsigned` and seems to be capable of storing the full number.

Comment: Yes. `std::chrono::milliseconds` is [defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) as _at least_ 45 bits; `nanoseconds` is _at least_ 64 bits. (facepalm)

Comment: @jwm That applies to the predefined `duration` convenience specializations, but I don't see anything that requires `system_clock` to use one of these or to satisfy the same requirements.

Comment: you are right, I don't see that either. We are probably in language-lawyer territory, and I haven't passed the Bar. The details appear to be left to the implementation, but I can't imagine a modern implementation that would not use a 64-bit type for anything more precise than seconds.